# Stopping imported html content overriding CSS

Tags: html, css, haml

I have a page on my site where I'm displaying HTML email.

Some of that email seems to come with CSS that overrides my site layouts such that certain things get misplaced...
e.g. I have a toolbar at the top of the page that on some mails covers the various header information from the email.

Is there a way of creating a div where I can put the html email with a layout that effectively says 'Stay in this div and don't bugger about with anything else'?

Worth noting that I have the html content as 'text' rather than referring to an external website. (It's actually a return from an API, but assuming the same restrictions apply)

```
%iframe{srccode: @mail.html}
```

Just gives me a blank iframe

Comment: Same idea with @Dave, you should use an iframe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include your mail using an IFrame similar to this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```

This will keep the styles separate

see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp for options to customize the IFrame

If using html as text (rather than referencing an existing page:

```
%iframe{srcdoc: "#{@mail.html}"} #for rails / haml
```

or

```
<iframe srcdoc="<your html as text>"></iframe>
```

Comment: I think this is definitely on the right lines, but I have the html code locally.

Comment: Then you can reference your iframe locally as well

Comment: <iframe src="content/file.html" width="100" height="100"></iframe>

Comment: You can reference it with something like that which is applicable on your side

Comment: Try saving the php generated file locally, I think you might be creating a  vitual/dynamic page. I don't know php that well so can't really help you there. We might need some more details on how you are generating the email to get you help

Comment: Ok. I'm being an idiot. this is fundamentlaly the correct answer. Just need to use 

    %iframe{srcdoc: "#{@mail.html}"} #for rails

or

    <iframe srcdoc="your html text here"></iframe>

Comment: Awesome! Good luck further!

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to incorporate the scoped style:

```
<div>
  <style scoped>
    h1 { color: FireBrick;   }
    p  { color: SaddleBrown; }
  </style>
  <h1>This is an H1 in a scoped div. Regardless of global styles the text should be "FireBrick".</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph in a scoped div. The text should be "SaddleBrown".</p>
</div>

<p>This is another paragraph, that will unaffected by the scoped style and remain black.</p>
```

*worth noting: this feature is still experimental and is not widely supported by 2015 browsers, currently, only FireFox v21.0+ supporting this feature. ([more info @ w3school.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_scoped.asp))*

Reference: https://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/

Comment: -1 for not stating that this feature is berarly supported by the browsers...
unless all your users use `FireFox v21.0+`, you should NOT use this as your only alternative! see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_scoped.asp

Comment: Well I wouldn't imagine anyone would implement something without fully understanding its capabilities (or lack of in this instance).

Comment: still, suggesting to use some experimental feature of future HTML should be stated as experimental (i would think).

Comment: Also, I prefixed the answer with "You may be able to...". The OP may be implementing this functionality on an internal application where he knows the browser capabilities. Or better yet, he uses a tool such as Modernizr to decide whether or not to implement this functionality depending on the browser capabilities. The point is that it's an option, a perfectly valid one at that.

Comment: My friend, i am not judging, i think your answer is good, and "out of the box idea", but was lacking a little detail... suggested an edit of the answer, accept if you like it.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the edit. It's also worth noting that this article was written in April 2012, so I'm guessing this functionality will never actually see the light of day across all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Dave's answer above

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```

is good for referencing an external site, or a page that exists as html.

If using html as text (rather than referencing an existing page):

```
%iframe{srcdoc: "#{@mail.html}"} #for rails / haml
```

or

```
<iframe srcdoc="<your html as text>"></iframe>
```

And then formatting the iframe to suit does the trick.